# PHP use of array_map array_shift to slice array into odd and even sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays

By definition, PHP's array_shift will return the first elem from the array and the array will downsize one.

I want to slice an array alternatingly into two sub-arrays, i.e index of 0,2,4,6,... and index of 1,3,5,7,...

I first break it into chunks of 2, then I use array_map to call array_shift. However, it is half correct (output below):

```
array1: Array ( [0] => greeting [1] => question [2] => response ) 
array2: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => greeting [1] => hello ) [1] => Array ( [0] => question [1] => how-are-you ) [2] => Array ( [0] => response [1] => im-fine ) )
```

Here's the code:

```
$a=array("greeting", "hello", "question", "how-are-you", "response", "im-fine");
$b=array_chunk($a, 2);
$c=array_map("array_shift", $b);
echo "array1: ";
print_r($c);
echo "array2: ";
print_r($b);
```

array2 does not seem to downsize after array_shift. Is this the correct behavior?  How can I do what I intend to do?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split array into two arrays by index even or odd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405264/split-array-into-two-arrays-by-index-even-or-odd)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this way to split your array alternatively **EVEN** and **ODD** keys, there may be many ways to do this, but this is my simple way using `array_walk`

```
$odd = [];
$even = [];
$both = [&$even, &$odd];
$array=["greeting", "hello", "question", "how-are-you", "response", "im-fine"];
array_walk($array, function($value, $key) use ($both) { $both[$key % 2][] = $value; });
print '<pre>';
print_r($even);
print_r($odd);
print '</pre>';
```

**RESULT:**
    Success time: 0.02 memory: 24448 signal:0

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => greeting
    [1] => question
    [2] => response
)
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => how-are-you
    [2] => im-fine
)
```

Comment: Hi, Being Human:  Thanks for the suggestions. The first works and the second prints out like this: Array
(
)
Array
(
)

Comment: @ShuangLiang see my edited answer, as i set $array variable in my first solution, so it was not set here, that's why you get Array(), check now...

Comment: Credit where credit is due;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405264/split-array-into-two-arrays-by-index-even-or-odd

Comment: @Being Human I see there is one way left. One way or the other, it counts as long as it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While this is already solved using array functions here is a low tech solution using a simple toggle to separate the odd and even elements...

```
$in = array("greeting", "hello", "question", "how-are-you", "response", "im-fine");

$i = 0;
$list = array();
foreach ($in as $text)
{
  $list[$i][] = $text;
  $i = 1 - $i;
}

print_r($list[0]);
print_r($list[1]);
```

Result...

```
Array ( [0] => greeting [1] => question [2] => response ) 
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => how-are-you [2] => im-fine )
```