# Foreach loop, show X odd items , then X even items

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Below i have a loop that will create two arrays of odd and evens numbers.
But what i really need is one loop, that goes through the `array` and gets first **4** **odd** items and show them  and then show next **4** **even** items, then next **4 odd** item and so on.

```
<?php       

    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
    $odd = array();
    $even = array();
    foreach($array AS $item){
         if ($item & 1) {
            $odd[] = $item ;            
         }else{
            $even[] = $item ;   
         }
    }
?>
```

i thought having two seprate arrays might make things simpler, but im unsure.

Comment: Your two arrays seems fine. After you make them, you can loop through each array in groups of 4 to print them.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: There is a solution to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405336/1694526

Comment: Use [this script with `$afterEvery = 4; $insertCount = 4;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73568281/2943403) like [this](https://3v4l.org/M5Sh1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First we get all even values into one array (`$even`) and all odd values into one array (`$odd`) with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Then we just simply loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), where we [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) both arrays into groups of 4. In the anonymous function we just simply [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the arrays with the result (`$mixed`) array.

```
<?php

        $array = range(1, 14);

        $even = array_filter($array, function($v){
            return $v % 2 == 0;
        });

        $odd = array_filter($array, function($v){
            return $v % 2 == 1;
        });

        $mixed = [];
        array_map(function($v1, $v2)use(&$mixed){
            $mixed = array_merge($mixed, $v1);
            $mixed = array_merge($mixed, $v2);
        }, array_chunk($even, 4), array_chunk($odd, 4));

        print_r($mixed);

?>
```

Then you can simply loop through your `$mixed` array. Like this:

```
foreach($mixed as $v)
    echo $v . "<br>";
```

output:

```
2 
4 
6 
8  
1 
3 
5 
7 
10 
12 
14 
9 
11 
13
```

Comment: this solution does look good, but wat happen if there more than 14 items in the array?