# PHP split string two parts by each other

Tags: php

I have string. for example

```
$string = 1234567;
```

or

```
$string = 1976324
```

How i can split each second. for example.

```
[0=>1357, 1=>246];
```

or

```
[0=>1734, 1=>962];
```

Comment: please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405264/split-array-into-two-arrays-by-index-even-or-odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a combination of str_split, array_chunk and array_column.
I am not recommending this, rather presenting another, alternate way of processing this that gave me some fun ;)

> **Note** : `array_column()` requires PHP 5.5+.

Example Code :

```
php > $string = 1234567;
php > print_r(array_column(array_chunk(str_split($string, 1), 2), 0));
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 7
)
php > print_r(array_column(array_chunk(str_split($string, 1), 2), 1));
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
)
```

Of course you may also concatenate that into strings:

```
php > echo implode('', array_column(array_chunk(str_split($string, 1), 2), 1));
246
php > echo implode('', array_column(array_chunk(str_split($string, 1), 2), 0));
1357
```

Comment: your answer not so good because eating extra resources. you calling twice 4 functions. for each iteration

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
<?php
$string = 1234567; 
$string = (string)$string;
$tmp[0] = "";
$tmp[1] = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string);$i++)
{
  if($i % 2)
  {
   $tmp[1] .= $string[$i];  
  }
  else
  {
   $tmp[0] .= $string[$i];
  }

}

print_r($tmp);
?>
```

Comment: If you ever edit this answer please also include an educational explanation.  Not every dev knows what the modulus operator does.