# PHP: Get array by 2 and store it to new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have empty array `$one` and `$two`

```
$one = [];
$two = [];
```

I have an array named **alpabhet**.

```
$alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
```

Is it posible to get the array like this:

```
$one = [
    0 => "A",
    1 => "C",
];

$two = [
    0 => "B",
    1 => "D",
];
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific errors/issues are you getting?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Is it possible to get the $alpabhet by 2 and store it to another array? Sorry Im new in php

Comment: PD:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405264/split-array-into-two-arrays-by-index-even-or-odd

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter()` and see if the key is even or odd. Use the constant `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` to pass the key-value to the callback instead of the value. This will work since the array you declared is numerically indexed, starting from 0.

```
$alphabet = ["A", "B","C","D"];
$one = array_filter($alphabet, function($key) {
    return !($key & 1); // Even keys
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$two = array_filter($alphabet, function($key) {
    return $key & 1; // Odd keys
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/dCu2l

This does however preserve the original keys of the array, so if you want to get the keys reassigned, you can use `array_values()` on the resulting array, see https://3v4l.org/jv0Od.

Comment: It the same code as on the link in comment

Comment: If you're wondering if I copied the code, no I did not - this is one approach (that I wrote up myself), but I'm not surprised if others have thought of it before - as its simple and does exactly what the question was asked.

Comment: Sorry that I have not closed it  immediately, but was hoping for a new approach

Answer (score 1):

You might use the [modulo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%` operator:

```
$alphabet = ["A", "B","C","D"];
$one = [];
$two = [];

foreach ($alphabet as $k => $v) {
    $k % 2 === 0 ? $one[] = $v : $two[] = $v;
}

print_r($one);
print_r($two);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => C
)
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => D
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop it like this

```
$alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

$one = [];
$two = [];


foreach ($alphabet as $key => $val) {
    if($key == 0 || ($key%2) == 0) {
        $one[] = $val;
    } else {
        $two[] = $val;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($one);
print_r($two);
```